# How to store multiple values in each item of a ListView?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have an array of items like:

```
items[0] = "Item 1";
items[1] = "Item 2";
...
```

And I fill my ListView list1 with this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
list1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

And I get the item value like this:

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String a = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
        ...
```

And works, but I really need to store more values in each item. For example, I want an item called "First item" to appear in the list, but when I click it, I get an associate value, like a number.

Example:

```
items[0] = {7,"First item"};
items[1] = {100,"Second item"};
```

I want only the "First item" and "Second item" appearing in the list, but when I click it, I retrieve the integers, in this case, 7 for the "First item" and 100 for the "Second item".

How can I achieve something like this? Thanks!

Comment: use a map and a simpleadapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store your return values in a second array?

```
items[0] = "first item";
items[1] = "second item";
value[0] = 7;
value[1] = 100;
```

Then grab the return value from the value array:

```
Log.i("SELECTED",item[position]);
Log.i("RETURNED",value[position]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `HashMap` to store Key as  **First item** and value as **7**   and like wise.

```
String[] items = { "First item", "Second item", "Third item"};

HashMap<String, Integer> hashmap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

           hashmap.put("First item", 7);
           hashmap.put("Second item", 100);
           hashmap.put("Third item", 200);

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
list1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String textValue = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
        int value=hashmap.get(textValue);
        System.out.println(textValue);
        System.out.println(value+"");
       }
```

**O/P: When clicking on first item.**

```
10-22 13:57:49.778: I/System.out(1038): First item
10-22 13:57:49.778: I/System.out(1038): 7
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your custom adapter, instead of using the ArrayAdapter. There is a BaseAdapter class that you can implement and as an array of data you could use a SparseArray. SparseArrays are generic and provide getters by index, its exactly what you need to feed a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) in place of ArrayAdapter.